# How to make this query condition optional in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am now now trying to make this route something like this.

```
localhost:3000/tasks?repeated=true&finished=false
```

As you can see in the route i want `repeated` & `finished` to be optional.
But my code below need both of them

```
router.get("/tasks", auth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // First way
    const match = {};
    if (req.query.finished) {
      match.finished = req.query.finished === "true";
    }
    if (req.query.repeated) {
      match.repeated = req.query.repeated === "true";
    }

    const task = await Task.find({
      owner: req.user._id,
    }).where({
      repeated: match.repeated,
      finished: match.finished,
    });

    res.send(task);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to build your own query condition, then put it into parameter in `find`.

```js
const query_condition = {
    owner: req.user._id
}

if (req.query.finished) {
    query_condition.finished = req.query.finished === "true";
}
if (req.query.repeated) {
    query_condition.repeated = req.query.repeated === "true";
}

const task = await Task.find(query_condition)
res.send(task);
```

Comment: Another Question
Can i limit the number of items returned?

Comment: `Task.find(query_condition).limit(number)`, such as `Task.find(query_condition).limit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following:

```
router.get("/tasks", auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
// First way
const match = {};
const task = await Task.find({
  owner: req.user._id,
}).where({
  repeated: req.query?.repeated,
  finished: req.query?.finished,
});

res.send(task);
```

or:

```
router.get("/tasks", auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
// First way
const match = {};
const task = await Task.find({
  owner: req.user._id,
}).where({
  ...(req.query?.repeated && { repeated: true}),
  ...(req.query?.finished && {finished: true}),
});

res.send(task);
```